# How do I set up a custom rake task to run acceptance tests using Capybara?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, rake, capybara

There is probably something I'm missing, but I have the following rake task set up:

```
namespace :test do
  Rake::TestTask.new(:acceptance => "test:prepare") do |t|
    t.libs << "test"
    t.pattern = 'test/acceptance/**/*_test.rb'
  end
end
```

I'm using Capybara for acceptance testing, so I've also included the following code in my `test_helper.rb` file:

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation

class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  # Make the Capybara DSL available in all integration tests
  include Capybara::DSL

  # Stop ActiveRecord from wrapping tests in transactions
  self.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  # Always use Selenium
  Capybara.default_driver = :selenium

  teardown do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean       # Truncate the database
    Capybara.reset_sessions!    # Forget the (simulated) browser state
    Capybara.use_default_driver # Revert Capybara.current_driver to      Capybara.default_driver
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, when I run `rake test:acceptance` I get the following error when rake tries to run a toy test called `selenium_test.rb`:

```
.../test/acceptance/selenium_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant ActionDispatch (NameError)
```

The file `selenium_test.rb` is in the `test/acceptance` folder of the app. If I move it to `test/functional`, it runs just fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to require the rails environment before your tests can run. You should add the require to the top of your `test_helper.rb`

```
require File.expand_path("../../../config/environment", __FILE__)
```

Of course the amount of `../` you have to do varies on the depth of your test folders. The config folder is located in the root of your application.

Comment: For brevity I didn't include my whole `test_helper.rb` file. I am already including the `environment.rb` config file. If I just run `rake test:units` for example, my tests run fine.

Answer (score 0):

as Yves suggested you probably need to load your rails application's environment.

Try to add :environment to the dependencies:

```
namespace :test do
  Rake::TestTask.new(:acceptance => ["test:prepare", :environment]) do |t|
    # Same as before
  end
end
```

As you see now the `test:acceptance` task depends not only on the `test:prepare` task but also on the `:environment` task.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had tried doing that a different way and also tried your suggestion just now, but to no effect...

Comment: Mmmm, I read again the question: Are you sure that your example test is run without problem when you move it in `/test/functional`? Or it's not run at all and then you don't have errors for this reason (no tests run)?

Comment: I'm certain it does run, because I'm using the Selenium driver, so I see Firefox start up and the test clicking around. It's really strange.